# SQL - Count word frequency

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which contains several columns. One of these columns contains a paragraph and each line has its own paragraph.
In each paragraph are words and I want to count doubles among all the column.

Example :

```
What is your name ?

Hello, my name is Quentin

His name is Quentin
```

The result must be :

```
 - Name - 3
 - is - 3
 - Quentin - 2
```

Comment: what do you mean by doubles ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  And is there a reason that you need to do this in SQL and not a procedural language?

Comment: I suggest you doing that with PHP, Java, C or whatever you're using

Comment: this is actually a difficult problem for SQL it's not geared for this sort of heavy text processing.

Comment: No way you can do this with SQL...

Comment: Thanks for answers ! No way to do this with SQL sure ? I want to use this language... Like I said to Gordon Linoff, in these paragraph there are # and I just want to count these #

Comment: It is not impossible to do this in pure MySQL, but MySQL was not designed to do this and you will probably suffer huge performance penalties if you implement this in MySQL. There are lot of theoretical problems as well, for example the definition of word.

Comment: Of what language do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

I would suggest that you create a new table that contains the "words" (however you define them) for each paragraph.

How you parse the words out is up to you.  One method would be to output the id for each row and then use a tool such as python to turn this into a structure such as:

```
id    word    pos
```

Then you can easily use this table to answer your question.

Comment: But in each paragraph there are # and I want to count these #

I want the easily way to count and classify these #

Comment: @QuentinCapra . . . SQL is the wrong tool for this query.